# Does there exist a quadratic polynomial $f \in K(x)[T]$ and $\Delta\in K[x]$ such that $f^2 + \Delta$ and $x^2-1+\Delta$ are both squares

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

Does there exist a number field $K$, not containing $i$, a quadratic polynomial $f\in K(x)[T]$, and an arbitrary polynomial $\Delta\in K[x]$ such that $f^2 + \Delta$ and $x^2-1 + \Delta$ are both squares?

Comment: What happened to the question about a conic and a simple field extension? I liked that one.

Comment: @WillJagy Someone (Mohan, I think) commented that it's obviously false. I mean, on any curve you can always come up with points which are of arbitrarily high degree over the base field. The property of conics that I had misremembered isn't that every point can be defined over a quad. ext, but that you can always find a point over a quadratic ext. Anyway, he didn't seem to want to make his comment an answer, so I deleted it the question (maybe I shouldn't have?)

Comment: I added in another variable to make it homogeneous, was fiddling with it. Sort of thing in Lam's Quadratic Forms Over Fields. I could not see why your idea would work...